# Winforms Grouping Gridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there anyway to create a grouping GridView in c# Winforms. for example I have the following data coulmns:
Manager name : Number of reportees : Reporting Manager name : Designation

I want this to be grouped based on designation as follows:
Project Manager
Manager name : Number of reportees : Reporting Manager name 
Associate Project Manager
Manager name : Number of reportees : Reporting Manager name

I have all the data in say Manager Collection.

Comment: Do you want a separate `GridView` for each designation, or how?

Comment: Nops, I want it to be a single gridview.

Comment: Unless you’re going to explain what you want, you won’t get help.

Comment: I have the gridview with the 4 columns as stated in the description. I want the columns to be grouped based on the Designation, so that it will have only three columns, with each designation header coming in between. Just like it is another gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following post has provided with a great sample.

http://blogs.vbcity.com/hotdog/archive/2008/12/19/9226.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the standard `DataGridView` will do what you want. [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/) has an `UltraGrid` control that has support for "group by", which sounds like what you want, but their controls are not free.

Comment: Every 3rd party component company that produces a grid will have this grouping feature built in. In fact, most have it annoyingly turned on by default. Besides Infragistics there is: DevExpress, Telerik, Exceed, Syncfusion and many more...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're missing any functions of the control that will do that for you, I think you need to find a way to use the controls you have to do what you want.

For example, from your 4-col grid, if they click on a cell with a designation 'project mgr', you can open/switch to your 3 col grid with all project manager details.